# How do I use the style.css file in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted this file to be the global styling sheet. But I don't know how to make a component reference it. Angular set-up here
[image: here is the angular setup]

Here is my component:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular-cli how to add global styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484937/angular-cli-how-to-add-global-styles) That's not how you add global styles, and not what angular [components are](https://angular.io/api/core/Component).

Comment: I believe it does. I see that it does not work the way that I thought it did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create components using angular cli, run the below command in the terminal where your project is located.
Command : ng generate component component_name

You can also check out this link
[angular-cli how to add global styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484937/angular-cli-how-to-add-global-styles)