# Applying ngStyle to all p tags within an html page

Tags: html, angular, ng-style

I am currently writing code for an Angular project that changes color dynamically based on the user selecting a theme. When a theme is selected it grabs from an api the hex code for the desired color to theme the app in, which for this I want to apply the theme color to all text. Currently I can apply it individually to each p tag through ngStyle by typing it as
`<p [ngStyle]="{'color': api.color}">` , though I want to be able to apply it to all instance of the p tag without repeating it for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Angular Global CSS file to apply global style. Here are the references:

1. [Angular Global CSS styles](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-global-css-styles/)
2. [angular-cli how to add global styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484937/angular-cli-how-to-add-global-styles)