Angular/CSS: How to style a component based on a built-in component's styling?
I am developing an Angular table library, and I have several components that can be used in place of the standard td or th elements. Currently, I am applying a style that applies to multiple of these components like so:
td,
elm-total-cell,
elm-editable-cell {
   border-bottom: $border;
}

Is there a cleaner way style these elements? I've had bugs pop up in cases where I forget to include the replacement component (i.e. let's say I forgot in the above example to include elm-total-cell). Ideally, if I apply a style to td, it would apply to all components that can be used in the place of td.

You should place these CSS rules in the global stylesheet of your Angular app. https://stackoverflow.com/q/37484937/8017690
